# Cordova iOS plugin install pod install silently exits

Tags: ios, cordova, jenkins

I am writing a script which automates the build of my Cordova App for iOS. 
I'm using CLI 6.4.0 and cordova-ios 4.3.1 and I use the new possibility to add a framework to the plugin as a pod. Plugin is specified like this in the config.xml:

```
<plugin name="sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding" spec="~0.0.4" />
```

and the plugin uses a framework as pod:

```
<framework src="SBBSMPLib" type="podspec"
    spec=":git => 'https://code.sbb.ch/scm/kd_cp/sbbsmplib-ios.git', :branch => 'develop'"/>
```

My script runs well on my MacBook. There I get the following output

```
...

Running `pod install` (to install plugins)
Running command: pod install --verbose
==== pod install start ====

  Preparing

....
```

Now I'm trying to run the script on a Mac Server of our Jenkins infrastructure. There the plugin installation fails with the following log:

```
Discovered plugin "sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding@~0.0.4"
Fetching plugin "sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding@~0.0.4" via npm
Copying plugin "/Users/admin/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding/0.0.4/package" => "/Users/admin/jenkins-slave/workspace/kd.esta.mobile.hybrid.onboarding-testapp.ios.developer/apps/onboarding-testapp/plugins/sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding"
Calling plugman.install on plugin "/Users/admin/jenkins-slave/workspace/kd.esta.mobile.hybrid.onboarding-testapp.ios.developer/apps/onboarding-testapp/plugins/sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding" for platform "ios
Installing "sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding" for ios
Running command: /Users/admin/jenkins-slave/workspace/kd.esta.mobile.hybrid.onboarding-testapp.ios.developer/apps/onboarding-testapp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Command finished with error code 0: /Users/admin/jenkins-slave/workspace/kd.esta.mobile.hybrid.onboarding-testapp.ios.developer/apps/onboarding-testapp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Finding scripts for "before_plugin_install" hook from plugin sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".
Install start for "sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding" on ios.
Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
Action stack processing complete.
Adding pods since the plugin contained <framework>(s) with type="podspec"
pods.json: The file at /Users/admin/jenkins-slave/workspace/kd.esta.mobile.hybrid.onboarding-testapp.ios.developer/apps/onboarding-testapp/platforms/ios/pods.json does not exist.
Creating new pods.json in platforms/ios
Wrote to pods.json.
Podfile: The file at /Users/admin/jenkins-slave/workspace/kd.esta.mobile.hybrid.onboarding-testapp.ios.developer/apps/onboarding-testapp/platforms/ios/Podfile does not exist.
Creating new Podfile in platforms/ios
Wrote to Podfile.
Set pods.json for `SBBSMPLib`
Added pod line for `SBBSMPLib`
Wrote to pods.json.
Wrote to Podfile.
Running `pod install` (to install plugins)
Failed to install 'sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding':undefined
Failed to restore plugin "sbb-cordova-plugin-onboarding" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Version should contain only numbers and dots
Saving ios@4.3.1 into platforms.json
No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add".
```

That is, 'pod install' does nothing.

So I guess the problem has to do with the configuration of the Jenkins Mac Server. Any idea what is going wrong and how I can get a more detailed error?

Thank

Comment: Cordova issue opened for this problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12272

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova issue opened for this problem https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12272